# How to compose directories structures with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build

I have directories structure like:

```
-first_dir
   -a
   -b
   -c
-second_dir
   -a
   -b
   -c
```

I would like to create a `path` element in Ant 1.7 without duplication. This `path`s elements I want to use for checking avalibility of files in `available` condition in `waitfor` task.
What is the way to do this?

Comment: Please show your expected output. Do you consider first_dir/a and second_dir/a as duplicates or is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what might help you (from Ant FileSet documentation):

```
<fileset dir="${server.src}" casesensitive="yes">
  <patternset id="non.test.sources">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
    <exclude name="**/*Test*"/>
  </patternset>
</fileset>
```

You could adjust it for your needs this way:

```
<path id="result.path">
    <fileset dir="first_dir" casesensitive="yes">
      <patternset id="sub.dirs">
        <include name="a"/>
        <include name="b"/>
        <include name="c"/>
      </patternset>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="second_dir" casesensitive="yes">
      <patternset refid="sub.dirs" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```